# Work with Subversion in Java, performance is VERY important

Tags: java, svn

I wanted to work with Subversion in Java. The most important thing for me is performance. I want to be able to run these commands:

- SVN Commit
- SVN Status
- SVN Add
- SVN Cat

Currently I run these commands in command line and each time I get the result as a string and process it. But this approach is not very good for performance so I'm looking for a new library to work with in Java.

Also if you provide a documentation for me to help me use that library it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking about subversion performance or your String parser's performance? If the latter then paste some code and a brief description of what you are trying to achieve. If the former then I have never seen the need for a super fast svn commit ... it has always worked reasonable fast for me.

Comment: I think reading the result from the command line and parsing it is slowing down my app a little.

Comment: In that case you should use a third party library like SVNKit mentioned by Joe below.

Comment: Parsing is highly unlikely to be a performance issue in your system. The operations like committing and updating over a network are far far more expensive.  However using a library like SVNKit is a better idea for a host a reasons, but performance is not one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. My current code is running perfectly without any problems. Do you think in this situation I should change my code to use SVNKit? (I thought using another library could improve the performance since it wasn't that good but if it isn't helping that much, what now?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/) (pure Java lib for Subversion.)

Comment: I've read about SVNKit a little but I wanna know if its performance is better or worse than using command line. Do you know which one is better?

Comment: I would guess the dedicated Java library will be better in performance than invoking command-line scripts -- and could make your code better 'integrated' with subversion.

Comment: Thanks. Just if it is possible could you please guid me how to use it in Eclipse? I downloaded the standalone and eclipse plugin version but I don't know how to use them. I'm very new to Java :-p You could save me from reading lots of documentation ;) Thanks again.

Comment: This is probably worth another question to the community, I'm not sure I'd really be able to help you much here.